# Conversion of Capital letters to Small letters using functions,arrays & Awk

Tags: shell, awk

How can I capitalize the first letter in every sentence of a file and convert the other capital letters to smalls (if any) and rewrite the modified text into the same input file?

Input File:

> tHiS is The tEst fIle.iT is uSEd for teSTing a sCript.whICh is useD
>   for ConverTing caPiTal leTTers to Small leTTers.

Comment: What's the definition of a "sentence" here?

Comment: when is the due date ?

Comment: It is some text file...taken for an example.

Comment: due date is as soon as possible :)

Comment: words after the "." can consider as sentense....

Comment: Can someone please suggest how to proceed on this...

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*)/\L\1/;s/((^|\.)\s*.)/\U\1/g' file
This is the test file.It is used for testing a script.Which is used for converting capital letters to small letters.

# Save changes to file
$ sed -ri 's/(.*)/\L\1/;s/((^|\.)\s*.)/\U\1/g' file
```

Comment: How can we get this by using arrays and awk?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [tr subroutine](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html) in Perl:

```
$ cat original-file.txt | perl -ne 'tr/A-Za-z/a-zA-Z/; print;' \
    > new-file-with-toggled-case.txt
$ mv new-file-with-toggled-case.txt original-file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
awk '{sub($0,tolower($0)); sub(/./, toupper(substr($0,1,1)))}1' RS=. ORS=. file
```

Output:

```
This is the test file.It is used for testing a script.Which is used for converting capital letters to small letters.
```

This would work for sentences ending in **.**, but not for exclamation mark, question marks etc.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple in perl if you want:

```
s/(\w+)/\u\L$1/g
```

check [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/02/capitalize-every-first-letter-of-word.html) or [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/caplitalizechange-to-uppercase-first.html) which are related to your query